# How to add custom header with sip REGISTER request

Tags: android, sip, linphone

Yesterday I took the latest `linphone` code and successfully compiled it for `Android`. I am able to register successfully and i am able to make calls.

Now I am trying to use our server with some `custom header`.
I was trying to find a way to add custom header in `REGISTER` request. But failed.

I have done this in iPhone using "linphone_proxy_config_get_custom_header" directly.

But in Android, the method itself not available in linphonecore_jni.cc. Also "addCustomHeader" in "LinphoneProxyConfig.java" file.

But I can see other implementation like;

  `1. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneInfoMessageImpl_addHeader

  2. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneCallParamsImpl_addCustomHeader

  3. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneCallParamsImpl_addCustomSdpAttribute

  4. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneCallParamsImpl_addCustomSdpMediaAttribute

  5. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneEventImpl_addCustomHeader

  6. Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneChatMessageImpl_addCustomHeader`

I don't know how to resolved this issue.

Any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

I modified 3 files to fix this issue.

`1.` I added the below code in `linphonecore_jni.cc` file.

```
extern "C" jstring Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneProxyConfigImpl_getCustomHeader(JNIEnv*  env
                                                                                  ,jobject  thiz
                                                                                  ,jlong ptr, jstring jheader_name) {
    const char *name=env->GetStringUTFChars(jheader_name,NULL);
    const char *value=linphone_proxy_config_get_custom_header((LinphoneProxyConfig*)ptr,name);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jheader_name, name);
    return value ? env->NewStringUTF(value) : NULL;
}

extern "C" void Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneProxyConfigImpl_addCustomHeader(JNIEnv*  env
                                                                               ,jobject  thiz
                                                                               ,jlong ptr, jstring jheader_name, jstring jheader_value) {
    const char *name=env->GetStringUTFChars(jheader_name,NULL);
    const char *value=env->GetStringUTFChars(jheader_value,NULL);
    linphone_proxy_config_set_custom_header((LinphoneProxyConfig*)ptr,name,value);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jheader_name, name);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jheader_value, value);
}
```

`2.` Then added below code in `LinphoneProxyConfigImpl.java` file:

```
    private native void addCustomHeader(long nativePtr, String key,String value);
    public void addCustomHeader(String key,String value) {
        isValid();
        addCustomHeader(nativePtr, key, value);
    }

    private native String getCustomHeader(long nativePtr, String key);
    public String getCustomHeader(String key) {
        isValid();
        return getCustomHeader(nativePtr, key);
    }
```

`3.` Then, added below code in `LinphoneProxyConfig` file.

```
void addCustomHeader(String key,String value);

String getCustomHeader(String key);
```

In my code, I am adding the `x-header` as below:

```
LinphoneProxyConfig proxyConfig = linphoneCore.createProxyConfig(----);
proxyConfig.addCustomHeader("X-Test1", "testing");
proxyConfig.addCustomHeader("X-Test2", "2nd test");
```

### UPDATE:

There is a method called `setCustomHeader` in latest `linphone` source.

```
proxyConfig.setCustomHeader("X-Test1", "testing");
proxyConfig.setCustomHeader("X-Test2", "2nd test");
```